What is the difference between pick() and c_across() in dplyr for counting missing data in rows?
Three sub-questions:

How are pick() and c_across() different?
How do I make the second code block work? I can't figure out how to combine the data types!
In looking at the documentation, they seem similar, but I would actually have guessed c_across() would be superior for this task. Why would pick() be a bad choice?

#Works
tibble(
  a_letter=sample(c(NA,"a","b"),size = 10,replace = T),
  a_number=sample(c(NA,1,2),size = 10,replace = T),
  hi="world"
) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(empty_measurements=sum(is.na(pick(matches("a_")))))

#Does not work:
tibble(
  a_letter=sample(c(NA,"a","b"),size = 10,replace = T),
  a_number=sample(c(NA,1,2),size = 10,replace = T),
  hi="world"
) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(empty_measurements=sum(is.na(c_across(matches("a_")))))


With rowSums across will suffice tb |> mutate(empt_msmnt = rowSums(across(starts_with("a_"), ~ is.na(.x)))). Read about the differences of pick and c_across here ?pick. Its mainly the return type.

You can use is.na(pick(matches("a_"))) |> rowSums() without going trough rowwise():
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
tibble(
  a_letter=sample(c(NA,"a","b"),size = 10,replace = T),
  a_number=sample(c(NA,1,2),size = 10,replace = T),
  hi="world"
) |> 
  mutate(empty_measurements = is.na(pick(matches("a_"))) |> rowSums())
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    a_letter a_number hi    empty_measurements
#>    <chr>       <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
#>  1 <NA>           NA world                  2
#>  2 <NA>           NA world                  2
#>  3 <NA>            1 world                  1
#>  4 <NA>            1 world                  1
#>  5 a               1 world                  0
#>  6 a               2 world                  0
#>  7 a               2 world                  0
#>  8 <NA>           NA world                  2
#>  9 b              NA world                  1
#> 10 b               2 world                  0

pick() returns tibble, so even if it just contains a single row, values there can have different types. With c_across() you work with a (row) vector, so type of all elements must be same.
